# SOLUCIONADO! Petición a backend funciona localmente, pero en host se rechazan

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, express, servidor, heroku

ACTUALIZACIÓN: *básicamente el problema es que heroku no escribe ni lee arhivos, por ende no puedo utilizar esa petición con heroku. Debo utilizar un servicio que permita la escritura.* **Muchas gracias por la ayuda!**

Me está ocurriendo un error a la hora de hacer una petición en mi backend. A la hora de probarlo en modo localhost las peticiones se realizan correctamente, funciona todo como debe, pero a la hora de subirlo por ejemplo a heroku, vercel. La petición POST me da code 500 sin especificarme un error legible. No sé qué podría ser. Agradezco toda ayuda.

Este es mi código que realiza el post. validateToken es el token que me genera jsonwebtoken para el acceso del usuario y upload.single es la funcion de multer para subir la image.

```
// Create article
router.post("/", validateToken, upload.single("image"), async (req, res) => {
  const image = req.file.filename;
  const article = req.body;
  const username = req.user.username;
  article.username = username;

  const newArticle = await Articles.create({
    ...article,
    image,
  });
  res.json(newArticle);
});
```

Esta es la respuesta en localhost
[image: código OK]

Esta es la respuesta una vez hosteado en heroku/vercel
[image: código error]

Y este es error en consola.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi configuración de entorno de modelo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco todo tipo de ayuda, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: bueno veo que en tu local lo haces con http y en produccion con https ... sera eso???

Comment: Nunca he usado Heroku, pero supongo que tendrá un log... debes es revisar el log allá a ver que es lo que está pasando, el porqué del error.

Comment: es un 500, tienes que ver si tu ruta a dónde apunta tu backend es la correcta, si tienes los controlador y modelos bien hecho, es un sin fin de posibilidades.

Comment: verifica que si para procesar la petición accedes a una variable de entorno onda `process.env.COSA` / `System.getenv("COSA")` etc... la misma sea definida para la instancia vía `heroku config:set COSA=valorcosa`. para debugging podes configurar el [remote debugging](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec#remote-debugging) o usar el típico `console.log` y luego  `heroku logs --tail --app {{NAME_OF_YOUR_APP}}`

Comment: @aloMalbarez Al final del post puse las variables que utilizo para la conexión con mis modelos. Será que debo agregar alguna de esas configs a heroku?

Comment: lo que normalmente meterías en un .env editable por consola ( valores, credentials y secrets que no se commitean ), lo configuras con el cli o el dashboard https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: Acabo de revisar bien los logs de heroku y básicamente el problema es que heroku no escribe ni lee arhivos, por ende no puedo utilizar esa petición con heroku. Debo utilizar un servicio que permita la escritura. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!